# Good Practice for Multiple Institutes DB Designing

Tags: database, mongodb, database-performance

Am new to database designing and am in learning to design a db to deal with multiple institutes.(ex: School Management Software which deals 
with multiple schools)

While designing db, which is the good practice, A single db for multiple institute or individual db for each institutes.

Please guide me for a better db design understanding.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible (and probably cheaper) to handle multiple institutions with a  single database. 
Reasons why this might not be a "good idea" are in realms such as politics and security. 
Given a free hand, I'd go for the single database approach.

Designing databases is not a simple matter. I suggest that you have a look at the free [NORMA tool](http://www.ormfoundation.org/files/folders/norma_the_software/default.aspx) because it can automatically generate a fully normalized schema - if you get the input right.
The [tutorials are here](http://www.ormfoundation.org/files/folders/normalabs/default.aspx).